# What does ‘ bolted a little out ‘ mean here?

Tags: meaning

> you have **bolted a little out** of the course, as young fellows often do; and you shall never have another chance, nor the ghost of half a one.' The wild young grandson makes answer to this and says, 'You're as rich as rich can be; you have been at no uncommon expense on my account, you're saving up piles of money for my little sister that lives with you in a secret, stealthy, hugger-muggering kind of way and with no manner of enjoyment—why can't you stand a trifle for your grown-up relation?' The jolly old grandfather unto this, retorts, not only that he declines to fork out with that cheerful readiness which is always so agreeable and pleasant in a gentleman of his time of life, but that he will bow up, and call names, and make reflections whenever they meet. Then the plain question is, an't it a pity that this state of things should continue, and how much better would it be for the gentleman to hand over a reasonable amount of tin, and make it all right and comfortable?”

Does it mean he ran away ?

Excerpt From *The Old Curiosity Shop* by Charles Dickens

Comment: Hello Asmaa,  Please use a dictionary to check the meaning of the verb "bolt" (it has several meanings but can you find any that fit better here.  Then [edit] the question to tell everyone what you have discovered.  It is good to show that you have done this before asking a question.

Comment: here is a link https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolt

Comment: You bungled the cut&paste! It's *...bolted out of **the** course* - without that article it looks like ***of course = naturally***, but ***with*** the article it obviously means *you've **strayed from the designated path** [that the speaker envisaged for the development of his young protege].* Note that this is a ***figurative*** usage. For all I know, the addressee metaphorically strayed from the path of righteousness by staying in and getting drunk every night. He didn't necessarily ***go*** anywhere else.

Comment: The cited example is a couple of centuries old, and wouldn't be likely today. But my guess is ***bolt out of the course*** is equivalent to current metaphoric usages such as ***go off the rails, stray from the straight and narrow, leave the reservation,...*** (apologies if that last one is now considered offensive).

Comment: ...and ***stand a trifle*** means ***spare / give a little bit** [of money]*

Comment: @FumbleFingers.  sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is "stand a trifle" bolded? Is that how it appared in the original text, or did you bold it for some reason?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan. I bolded it .

Comment: @MarcInManhattan.  Here’s  the original text https://books.apple.com/sa/book/the-old-curiosity-shop/id498917227

Comment: @Asmaa Got it. I removed the bold type since there doesn't seem to be any reason for it.

Comment: The term "to bolt" is often used for lettuces and cabbages to this day.  It means instead of forming a head, the plant sends up a long vertical flower stalk (which often happens with lettuces in hot, dry weather ... less often with modern brassicas). This may be the direct origin of Dickens' figurative usage.  This might help explain how "a little" fits into the context. It's otherwise a little hard to understand how someone could "bolt a little".  You can't after all fire a bolt "a little" from a crossbow.

Comment: The above-described sense of bolt is not included in the Cambridge entry linked above, presumably either as an oversight or because the dictionary makers interpret it as a figurative usage of the sense of (something like) "to move away quickly" like a crossbow bolt.

Comment: Merriam-Webster includes the horticultural meaning (sense 5. of the intransitive verb):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt